# php Illegal offset while appending to array

Tags: php, arrays, google-analytics

So I'm trying to change an array that I have;

```
  +rows: array:31 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "20190101"
      1 => "5"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "20190102"
      1 => "15"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "20190103"
      1 => "17"
    ]
```

To modify the index 0 of each row to a Carbon DateTime Object for further processing.

Now I'd like to have a json output, but I currently even can't get rid of the `Illegal offset type` error....

The code I'm using to retreive the data (from GoogleAnalytics) is the follwing:

```
$get_stats = Analytics::performQuery(
    Period::create(Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()),
    'ga:users',
    [
        'dimensions' => 'ga:date',
        'samplingLevel' => 'HIGHER_PRECISION',
        'include-empty-rows' => true
    ]
);
```

This returns alot of code, but I just grab the `$get_stats->rows` (see above for that output).

I then make a new array, defined as `$stats = [];`.

A loop iterates over the `$get_stats->rows`, so I can 'modify' the data in the array and append it to the newly created array.

```
foreach ($get_stats->rows as $value)
{
    $stats[] = [Carbon::createFromFormat('Ymd', $value[0]) => $value[1]];
}
```

However I get (always) the `Illegal offset type` error, on the line with `$stats[] = [Carbon::createFromFormat('Ymd', $value[0]) => $value[1]];`

Can someone help me out with this? I have no clue why it does this, when I try to append an array to an array. I tried `array_push()`, gives the same issue, also `array_merge` has the same issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `Carbon::createFromFormat('Ymd', $value[0])` returns a `Carbon` **object**, and objects are not valid array indexes. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by doing this conversion on the key, it seems a simple

```
$stats[] = [$value[0] => $value[1]];
```

or even

```
$stats[$value[0]] = $value[1];
```

might be more useful to you. You can always do the conversion to a `Carbon` object when you want to display the data.

Comment: Oh god.... Well, I just parsed the carbon object to a `Y-m-d`-format, that I can use... haha god... Why did I do such stupid thing, this is basic knowledge...